# FontLoader doesn't work properly with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js, syntax-error

I am using threejs in a vue project and
I faced the same error as [this](https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000023766820###) when I was trying to create a text geometry even though the path to the typeface font is correct and it's json

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, however I didn't figure out why `loader.load` was throwing this error. I solved it using `loader.parse`

Import the typeface json

```
import fontJson from "/src/assets/font/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json";
```

Use `loader.parse` instead

```
const font = loader.parse(fontJson);
```

If this won't work you aswell, maybe something is wrong with your JSON. I am sorry :(